# CSS rotation and text distortion

Tags: css, css-transforms

Creating a spreadsheet-style view and rotating the column causes the text to distort in Chrome + Firefox. I've managed to work around the Chrome issue using:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

However I'm left with Firefox looking like this :

[image]

Chrome (with fix)

[image]

Oddly IE 10 renders this perfectly - and Mac browsers do a better job too.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As of Firefox v16, Mozilla implements the unprefixed backface-visibility property, which might work for you:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
        backface-visibility: hidden;
```

IE10 will pick this up as well.

More information on the MDN [backface-visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)