# transform:rotate 5deg on menu distorts the text

Tags: css, transform

I have the simple code for menu

```
<nav class="top-menu">
        <li class="glavnaja">Главная</li>
        <li>Новости</li>
        <li>Выставки</li>
        <li>Распродажи</li>
        <li>Вакансии</li>
        <li class="last-li">Форум</li>
        </nav>
```

I tried to set transform:rotate on class "glavnaja"

```
.glavnaja {
    transform:rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
        backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

but after that i saw the text distortion. I found this topic [CSS rotation and text distortion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321608/css-rotation-and-text-distortion) but its not working. I will be very greatfull for advice how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and Mozilla. In both the same situation. I set inline-block on <li>, then set display:block; float:left on <li> and the same situation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Transforms will often cause blurriness when calculating subpixel values, it's just the nature of the beast.

One solution is to add `perspective` and `backface-visibility` values to the container, like so:

```
.top-menu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.glavnaja {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

In Webkit it certainly helps, and Firefox appears to have cleared up, too.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/eGHoh

Also, you should note that you still need to nest `<li>` elements inside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. They can't just hang out in a `<nav>` element by themselves!

Comment: shshaw, thank you so much for advice about <li> and for codepen! I set font-size: 20px and now its look perfect in both FF and Chrome!!!